# How to convert a hardcoded website to a PHP MVC framework site?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I would like to convert our college's hard coded website.

Should i follow any pattern to achieve efficient & fast Conversion ?

kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is one thing, but why not try to pry it into two sections first?

For instance, think of it as two parts communicating with each other, there's the *client* and *server*.

The "*client*" part is what contains the elements for display and passes actions by the user to the "*server*".

Now the "*server*" should contain everything else, for now. Your "*client*" part is what will eventually become V(iew).

Once this works, you can concentrate on prying the "*server*" into M and C, your "*client*" part will probably have some C parts in it, too.

Anyways, that's the general rule I follow, when converting and not redesigning.

Comment: Whatever works better I'd say.
First, identify what data you want to display:
should it be more of a news-site, more like a portfolio, or something that aggregates information.

I'm a big Wiki fan, and on the other hand, I feel that blog-style web pages are often misplaced. I use Wikis for anything that aggregates data, and where texts need to be changed quite often, without the need to produce news-like entries.

Answer (score 1):

This depends how much specific PHP code you have to handle... You would use a PHP framework only in the case you have to build functionalities which a regular CMS does not provide.